Colour spectrum before Newton's discoveries hinted at in the Kabbalah?
Sha'arei Tzedek 10 (c.1300):

ודע כי תחלת כל המראות לבן והוא מקבל כל הגוונים וסוף כל המראות שחור ואין אחריו גוון
Know that the beginning of all visions is white, which absorbs all colours, and the end of all visions is black, beyond which there is no colour

This is ostensibly talking about colours in the Sefirot, but the whole passage is making references to the way this manifests in the physical in various ways, including the Kohen's white garments etc.
This therefore seems like it is a revelation of knowledge about the colour spectrum, 400 years before Newton's famous prism experiment revealing that white is composed of all the colours.
Is this something special, or was there general knowledge that white "absorbs all colours" before Newton? Has anyone discussed that?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
